# Unable to delete a user from the admin side (IntegrityError at /admin/register/user/26/delete/)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am unable to delete a user from the django admin site as the following error keeps popping up (I'm fairly new to coding as well):

> IntegrityError at /admin/register/user/26/delete/

[image]

these are my codes:

**models.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username")
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a first name")
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a last name")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'balance']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import RegistrationForm
from .forms import TransferForm
from .models import User


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if Form.is_valid():
            Form.save()
            return redirect('sucreg')
    else:
        Form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'regpage.html', {'form': Form})


def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Form = AuthenticationForm(request, request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            # User is found in the database, log in the user
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('homepage')
        else:
            # User is not found in the database, show an error message
            error_message = 'Invalid login credentials. Please try againnnnn.'
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': error_message})
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')

def transfer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TransferForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recipient_username = form.cleaned_data['recipient_username']
            amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']

            try:
                recipient = User.objects.get(username=recipient_username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                error_message = "Recipient's username not found"
                return render(request, 'transfer.html', {'error_message': error_message})

            if recipient == request.user:
                error_message = "You cannot transfer money to yourself"
                return render(request, 'transfer.html', {'error_message': error_message})

            if request.user.balance < amount:
                error_message = "You do not have sufficient balance"
                return render(request, 'transfer.html', {'error_message': error_message})

            request.user.balance -= amount
            recipient.balance += amount

            request.user.save()
            recipient.save()

            messages.success(request, f"Transferred {amount:.2f} to {recipient_username}")
            return redirect('transfersuccess')
    else:
        form = TransferForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'transfer.html', context)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

from .models import User


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password']

    def clean_confirm_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        if password and confirm_password and password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return confirm_password

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.balance = 1010.00
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class AuthForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        username = cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    'Invalid login credentials. Please try again!!!.'
                )
            elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    'This account has been deactivated.'
                )
        return cleaned_data

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache


from django import forms


# User = get_user_model()

class TransferForm(forms.Form):
    recipient_username = forms.CharField(label="Recipient's username")
    amount = forms.DecimalField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['recipient_username'].widget.attrs.update({'id': 'recipient_username'})
        self.fields['amount'].widget.attrs.update({'id': 'amount'})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

I tried debugging it but couldn't solve it myself. I am expecting the user to be deleted.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I removed intelij mentions since nothing in the issue seems to be related to used IDE. Feel free to bring it back if you think otherwise.

Comment: Do you have other models in the project which have references to `User` model? _Were_ there any such models which have been removed from the project?

Comment: This error means that this user is link in other model probaly with option on_delate=models.DO_NOTHING

Comment: Hi @IvanStarostin, thanks for your response. No I do not have any other models in my project nor has there been one.

Comment: The error is clearly saying that in DB you do have Foreign Key referencing your User model. Try to look into tables using DBeaver or some other IDE for working with DB and find out what FK exist there. Also if you have some additional packages installed - please add list of INSTALLED_APPS to your question. The issue can be with one of them.  Also try running makemigrations/migrate or consider to kill and recreate your DB. Shown code does not have any foreign keys defined - the problem source is elsewhere.